# Continuous dual basis in a normed space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space (not necessarily complete) and $\{w_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset X$ be
a linearly independent set. Let $\{x^*_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a set of linear functionals on $X$ with the property that $x_i^*(w_j)=\delta_{ij}$. These linear functional are not necessarily bounded.

My question is the following: Is there any linear transformation (an analogue to Gramm-Schmidt procedure) that creates a new linearly independent set $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, such that
$$
\mathrm{span}\,\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}=\mathrm{span}\,\{w_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N} \subset X,
$$ 
and for which the existence of a bounded dual set $\{u^*_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset X^*$, i.e., $u_i^*(u_j)=\delta_{ij}$, is guaranteed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. We can ensure that ${\rm span}(u_1, \ldots, u_k) = {\rm span}(w_1, \ldots, w_k)$ and $\|u_k^*\| = 1$ for each $k$. The construction goes by induction on $k$. For $k = 1$ let $u_1 = \frac{1}{\|w_1\|}w_1$ and use Hahn-Banach to find $u_1^* \in X^*$ such that $\|u_1^*\| = u_1^*(u_1) = 1$. Inductively suppose $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ and $u_1^*, \ldots, u_k^*$ are chosen so that ${\rm span}(u_1, \ldots, u_k) = {\rm span}(w_1, \ldots, w_k)$ and so that $\|u_i^*\| = 1$ and $u_i^*(u_j) = \delta_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq k$. Then we can find $u_{k+1} \in \bigcap_{i=1}^k {\rm ker}\, u_i^*$ such that ${\rm span}(u_1, \ldots, u_{k+1}) = {\rm span}(w_1, \ldots, w_{k+1})$; an explicit formula is
$$u_{k+1} = w_{k+1} - \sum_{i=1}^k u_i^*(w_{k+1})u_i.$$
Define a linear functional $\tilde{u}_{k+1}^*$ on this span such that $\tilde{u}_{k+1}(u_i) = \delta_{i,k+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k+1$; by scaling $u_{k+1}$ we can ensure that $\|\tilde{u}_{k+1}^*\| = 1$. Then use Hahn-Banach to extend $\tilde{u}_{k+1}^*$ to $X$ without increasing its norm.

Comment: Thnx! - Although, I was expecting $u^*_i(u_j)=\delta_{ij}$, for all $i,j$.

Comment: Yes, my construction achieves $u_i^*(u_j) = \delta_{ij}$ for all $i, j$. Each $u_{k+1}$ is chosen to lie in the intersection of the kernels of all $u_i^*$ for $i \leq k$, so we get $u_i^*(u_j) = 0$ for $i < j$; beyond that, we only have to worry about $u_{k+1}^*(u_j)$ for $j \leq k+1$, and the construction explicitly handles that.

Comment: If you scale $u_{k+1}$ to ensure $\left\|\tilde u_{k+1}^\ast\right\|=1$, you lose the property that $\left\|u_{k+1}\right\|=1$, don't you?

Comment: Correct. I believe you can achieve $\|u_k\| = \|u_k^*\| = 1$ in finite dimensions --- there's a name for this kind of basis which I forget --- but it's probably not possible in infinite dimensions.

Comment: @NikWeaver It is called "Auerbach basis". I'd be interested in whether we can obtain the result in finite dimension using your approach. I only know a proof using the determinant.

Comment: Yes, Auerbach basis, thank you!! I don't see how my argument here could be straightforwardly used to get this. I feel like you have to get an Auerbach basis all at once, you can't construct it element-by-element like I am doing here.